What is the issue for Invalid Session Id 401 Unauthorized Salesforce Chrome Extension?
I'm developing a simple chrome extension and getting sid cookie value for salesforce but when i make a fetch request to using the session id value i am getting an error stating
scripts.js:73 Error: Unable to retrieve Apex classes. Status code: 401, Response: [{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]

I'm adding my code below
document.getElementById('token-cls').addEventListener('click', getToken);

function getToken() {
    console.log('Method Called_TokenGet');

    chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
        console.log(tabs[0].url);
        console.log('CurrentActiveTabs==>', tabs[0].url);

        // Get the base URL by splitting the full URL
        let domain = tabs[0].url.split('/')[2]; // Extracts 'amagi--uat.sandbox.lightning.force.com'
        let cookieUrl = tabs[0].url.split('/lightning/page/home')[0];
        console.log('Cookie URL:', cookieUrl);

        // Fetch the cookies for this base URL
        chrome.cookies.getAll({ url: cookieUrl }, function (cookies) {
            if (cookies.length > 0) {
                console.log('Cookies for ' + cookieUrl + ':', cookies);

                // Filter for the 'sid' cookie
                let sidCookie = cookies.find((cookie) => cookie.name === 'sid');

                if (sidCookie) {
                    console.log('SID Cookie:', sidCookie);
                    console.log('SessionId:', sidCookie.value);
                    if (sidCookie.value) {
                        retrieveApexClassesInfo(domain, sidCookie.value);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log('No SID cookie found');
                }
            } else {
                console.log('No cookies found for ' + cookieUrl);
            }
        });
    });
}

async function retrieveApexClassesInfo(domain, sessionId) {
    console.log('Session ID:', sessionId);
    // Define the Tooling API query to retrieve Apex class information
    const query = 'SELECT Id, Name, NamespacePrefix, SymbolTable FROM ApexClass';

    try {
        // Construct the request URL for Tooling API (replace 'v54.0' with your current Salesforce API version if needed)
        const toolingApiUrl = `https://${domain}/services/data/v61.0/tooling/query?q=${encodeURIComponent(query)}`;
        console.log('Tooling API URL:', toolingApiUrl);

        // Execute the Tooling API query
        const response = await fetch(toolingApiUrl, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${sessionId}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });

        // Check if the response is OK
        if (response.ok) {
            const jsonResponse = await response.json();
            const records = jsonResponse.records;

            // Iterate through the records and process each Apex class
            records.forEach(record => {
                const className = record.Name;
                const namespacePrefix = record.NamespacePrefix;

                console.log(`Apex Class Name: ${className}`);
                console.log(`Namespace Prefix: ${namespacePrefix}`);
                // Process additional information as needed
            });
        } else {
            console.error(`Error: Unable to retrieve Apex classes. Status code: ${response.status}, Response: ${await response.text()}`);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Exception occurred:', error.message);
    }
}

I am invoking this script from button from html nothing much , what could be the issue ?
